# Can't run pod install because conflict error

Tags: ios, xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

I am trying to install new pods in my project, but everytime i run 'pod install' this error pops up.

```
Unable to activate xcodeproj-0.14.1, because activesupport-4.0.0.rc1 conflicts with activesupport (~> 3.0)
```

I already search but i can't find any solution to this problem, can someone help me please.

Comment: it seems like your older version is trying to fail your new one, can you uninstall old one?

Comment: Thanks @Retro i ended up uninstalling rails 4.0.0 and activesupport and all went back to normal